# How to calculate summation of square of numbers in array in CFML

Tags: cfml

I am solving kata on `codewars`. Simple challenge, but I struggle to debug my `CFML` code.

Task is to square each number in array `numbers` and return summation of these squares.

**Here is my solution:**

```
component {
    numeric function squareSum(required Array numbers) {
        numeric result = 0;
        for (numeric i = 1; i <= arrayLen(numbers); i++) {
            result = result + (numbers[i] * numbers[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and here is the error:

```
template:Missing [;] or [line feed] after expression:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coldfusion is not a strongly typed language. So `numeric` is not needed on the variable definition. But function return type `numeric` is allowed.

```
component {
    numeric function squareSum(required Array numbers) {
        result = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(numbers); i++) {
            result = result + (numbers[i] * numbers[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=4ae8402f-9b84-49e3-9a8b-decd173fbde8/2faf583d-790d-4b5e-bd92-85c8c2ea1759/3f0b3732-604a-4353-ae79-5ce32703d6f3.cfm)

Comment: this has solved the problem. My original error message seemed to be misleading for beginner in ```CFML```